# How can I group data in mogodb plus merge two fields into a single field?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

Is there anyway to get from here:

```
{ "_id" : { "name" : "User1", "dept" : "A", "Code" : "Code1", "count" : 4 } }

{ "_id" : { "name" : "User2", "dept" : "B", "Code" : "Code1", "count" : 7 } }

{ "_id" : { "name" : "User1", "dept" : "A", "Code" : "Code2", "count" : 4 } }
```

to here:

```
{ "_id" : { "name" : "User1", "dept" : "A", "Code1" : "4", "Code2": "4" }}

{ "_id" : { "name" : "User2", "dept" : "B", "Code1" : "7" }}
```

I have tried using the mongodb aggregation framework, but cannot get it to work the way I want.

Comment: Please show what you tried and what went wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this :

```
db.yourCollectionName.aggregate([{
    $group: {
        _id: { name: '$_id.name', dept: '$_id.dept' },
        data: { $push: { $split: [{ $concat: ["$_id.Code", ",", { $toString: "$_id.count" }] }, ','] } }
    }
},
{
    $replaceRoot: { newRoot: { $mergeObjects: ['$_id', { $arrayToObject: "$data" }] } }
}])
```

**Explanation :**

1. Here we're grouping on `name` & `dept` plus doing concatenation of
   `Code` & `count` as string & splitting those two into an array.
2. Then
   we would convert `data` array to object plus merge it with `_id`
   object & making final object as new root.

**Test it here :** [MongoDB-Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/EKpNNbxIiRy)

Above should get you required output but if you want values `"Code1" : "4", "Code2": "4"` as numbers instead of string as input document has `count` field type as `int`, then try this :

```
db.yourCollectionName.aggregate([{
    $group: {
        _id: { name: '$_id.name', dept: '$_id.dept' },
        data: { $push: { $split: [{ $concat: ["$_id.Code", ",", { $toString: "$_id.count" }] }, ','] } }
    }
}, {
    $addFields: {
        data: {
            $map:
            {
                input: "$data",
                as: "each",
                in: [{ $arrayElemAt: ['$$each', 0] }, { $toInt: { $arrayElemAt: ['$$each', 1] } }]
            }
        }
    }
},
{
    $replaceRoot: { newRoot: { $mergeObjects: ['$_id', { $arrayToObject: "$data" }] } }
}])
```

Only change would be since we've converted `count` field from number to string in `$group` stage for concatenation we're converting it back to number.

Test it here : [MongoDB-Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/xsR_MBcvRfG)